# alignin 2 divs keeps one going down vertically

Tags: css, alignment

I'm having headaches aligning 2 divs. I've read many tutorials where two divs, one with float left the other float right, are used. Here is the code I'm using. The problem is that the image in div "fotosder" is going down if the browser is resized or a lower resolution is used.

Here is my code:

```
<li>
    <div class="holder_slogan">
         <p class="slogan"> slogan </p>


        <div class="social_buttons2">
    <div class="inset">
        <a class="fb login_button" href="http://xxx.com/facebook?next=xxx">
            <span class="logo_wrapper"><span class="logo"></span></span>
            <span>Facebook</span>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="registrate">
    <img src="data/images/registrate.png" alt="registrate" />
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

<div class="fotosder"><img src="images/imagen1.jpg" alt="listad" /></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div></li>


.sp-slider > li {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in 0.8s;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.holder_slogan {
    float: left;
    margin: 66px 0 0 18%;
    width: 387px;
}

#board .slogan, #board2 .slogan {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 470px;
}

.social_buttons2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 220px;
}

.fotosder {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 18% 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 329px;
}

.sp-slider > li img {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

img {
    border-style: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: the problem is with your margin %, set it to some fixed value and then try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. When the wrapping element is not wide enough to fit the two floated elements, one will go under the other. The right floated in this case as it is "last" in the document flow.

If you're worried about this, give the elements a % width and they shouldn't re-arrange unless they get extremely small or the contents of the elements prevent them from shrinking further.

Comment: Thanks for replying kyle. Using your solution resizes the image. The idea is to maintain same size, if someone resizes just a bit the browser the image is shown really small. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Tinku Rana If I change margin % the divs separate from each other. I need them centered and with a small separation between divs.

Comment: Is there any form to fix them together? I want the divs to be centered if the browser is resized, inline and with a small separation (30 px) between them

Comment: You can use CSS @media queries to detect browser sizes and re-write the rules regarding the two divs :)